# Why can't return ( (a++) %4)

Tags: c

I have a C function:

```
static uint8_t func( uint8_t a )
{
   return ( (a++) % 4 );
}
```

When I call it:

```
uint8_t b = 0;
b = func(b);
```

I found `b` still is 0 not 1. Why?

Comment: Google for "passing arguments by value and by reference difference"...

Comment: Pass the value of b with its reference rather just value.

Comment: `a++` is post increment operator. Use `++a`.

Comment: @Avinash : `b = func(b)` will anyways assign new value to `b`.

Comment: @Betlista `passing arguments by value and by reference difference` this is not come in picture.

Comment: `return (a+1)%4;` You are incrementing AFTER use.

Comment: Well, the question is *why* did you expect it to return `1`??? The function is clearly written to return `0`. Unless you explain why you expected it to return `1`, we won't know what the source of your confusion is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use post increment, the value will be incremented after the expression is evaluated.
That means First it will substitute `a` in expression and evaluate it, after the completion of evaluation it will increment `a`.

```
return ( (a++) % 4 );
```

here it will take as

```
return ( (0) % 4 ); // after this expression is solved 'a' becomes 1
```

If you want to return `1` use pre-increment-

```
return ( (++a) % 4 );
```

In this case before evaluating the expression it will increment `a`.

```
return ( (1) % 4 ); // so it will return 1.
```

or

```
return ((a+1)%4);
```

you can use above expression also. it wont modify the value of `a` what you have received.

Comment: +1, but expressions are *evaluated*, not *solved.*

Comment: Why modify a at all. `return (a+1)%4;` is by far the cleanest

Answer (score 4):

because

```
return ( (a++) % 4 );
```

is similar to

```
uint8_t result = a%4;
a = a + 1;
return result;
```

Try

```
return (++a) % 4;
```

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
return ( (a++) % 4 );
```

is equivalent to:

```
unit8_t temp =  ( a % 4 );
a++;
return temp;
```

That's how postfix increment operators work. The evaluate to their value and increment the value of objects after the expression they are used in has been evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

You use the post-increment operator which increments **after** the expression is evaluated.

So the expression `(a++) % 4` yields the same value as `a % 4`.

However, there's no point modifying the parameter, passed by value of course. Write it like this:

```
static uint8_t func(uint8_t a)
{
    return (a+1) % 4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   return ( (a++) % 4 );
```

change to

```
   return ( (++a) % 4 );
```

You will get what you want

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `++a` because in `a++` increment is done after using the value of a
and in `++a` value is used after the increment.

Answer (score -1):

You can modify your code as:

```
static void func( uint8_t *a )
{
  *a=++(*a) % 4;
}
```

and call it with:

```
uint8_t b = 0;
func(&b);
```

Comment: In that case `post ++` is also good to work with.

Comment: yep, i know it also works fine with post increment. But it need extra bracket. That's why used pre increment.

Comment: Passing address of variable is a terrible mistake. Now I cannot pass literals.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Yes. I got my mistake.

Comment: Your edit is even worse. Now it doesn't even compile. Pass by value.

Comment: And still you persist passing the address. Why do you use both assignment and pre-increment?

Comment: -1, horrible suggestion.

Comment: Just suggesting him in another point of view cause other's suggested it as a call by value.